# Display text in a table if value is null

Tags: visualforce

I currently have two objects, Opportunity and Step Review which are in a master detail relationship. I am currently getting all Opportunities and displaying two boolean values from step review. I want the data table to display 'false' even if the Step Review does not exist for the Opportunity. Here is the code for the VF page (Initial Capture Plan and Budget Approved are fields from the Step Review object):

```
<apex:column headerValue="Initial Capture Plan Approved">
    <apex:repeat value="{!acc.step_reviews__r}" var="accr">
        <apex:outputText value="{!accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c}" rendered="{!accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c != null}"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText  rendered="{!accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c == null}"> False </apex:outputText>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Capture / B & P Budget Approved">
    <apex:repeat value="{!acc.step_reviews__r}" var="accr">
        <apex:outputText value="{!accr.Capture_B_P_Budget_Approved__c}" rendered="{!accr.Capture_B_P_Budget_Approved__c != null}"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText  rendered="{!accr.Capture_B_P_Budget_Approved__c == null}"> False </apex:outputText> 
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
```

I also tried the following which doesn't work as well. Flag is set to False on the controller:

```
    <apex:column headerValue="Initial Capture Plan Approved">
    <apex:repeat value="{!acc.step_reviews__r}" var="accr">
        <apex:outputText value="{!accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c}" rendered="{!accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c != null}"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value= "{!flag}" rendered="{!accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c == null}">  </apex:outputText>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Capture / B & P Budget Approved">
    <apex:repeat value="{!acc.step_reviews__r}" var="accr">
        <apex:outputText value="{!accr.Capture_B_P_Budget_Approved__c}" rendered="{!accr.Capture_B_P_Budget_Approved__c != null}"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value= "{!flag}" rendered="{!accr.Capture_B_P_Budget_Approved__c == null}"> </apex:outputText> 
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparison is performed with `==`, not `=`. Not sure if that will fix your code but it is the most obvious flaw. You might try:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!BLANKVALUE(accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c, 'False')}" />
```

IF your field is a checkbox, use:

```
BLANKVALUE(TEXT(accr.Initial_Capture_Plan_Approved__c), 'False')
```

Comment: Fixed that in my code, however 'false' is still not displaying in the data table.

Comment: @Alex Try using `BLANKVALUE`.

Comment: Got the error: 'Incorrect argument type for function 'BLANKVALUE()'

Comment: @Alex What data type is the field you're trying to display?

Comment: The two fields are checkboxes.

Comment: @Alex Look at my updated answer, wrap their value in `TEXT` and it should work.

Comment: It still doesn't play well with that: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Boolean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40230/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-alex).